# How to show a table of content (TOC) for a text document in KDE's Kate?

Tags: kde, editors, kate, notes

Is it possible to show a Table of Content (TOC) in Kate for text documents such as txt files or files without filetype?

Maybe it's possible with some setting that I haven't found or with some plugin (maybe there's a plugin for it that isn't available in the options you can select under Settings->Configure Kate). If so, please describe how one can enable a TOC.

It would be useful to organize notes, todos and other texts into separate sections. Clicking on a section in the TOC would make you jump to it.

The text has the syntax "Normal" (this should work with default settings when simply opening a txt file and *not* require you to select the Markdown syntax for example).
For example, if you then write "####This is is a header" somewhere in the txt document, it would display just like all the other text in the file (no color-highlighting or necessarily headers that have a larger font-size) but still make this show up as a section in the TOC which is shown in the panel on the left beneath (not instead) the "Documents" tab if you have that view open there.

I created **[an issue requesting this feature here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=453577)** but haven't received a reply yet and it may already be possible with some plugin/option/separate tool/Kate-fork/workaround.

I have Kate v20.12.2 in Debian11/KDE.

Comment: There is no standard for how to define chapters etc in plain text without markup. Instead of introducing your own definition better use an existing markup language or use a rich text editor like LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: Should have clarified this here too (it's in the linked issue): the syntax would be easily configurable by the user, there is no other markup-syntax used here at all...only TOC-headers (default could be something like ####). LibreOffice is inappropriate for notes and similar txt files. Markdown as language does all kinds of color-highlighting in the txt file, you first need to switch to it to enable the TOC and the txt file may not be written in Markdown; this really is just for the TOC. Good point though.

Comment: Do you know of any plain text editor with this feature for comparison?

Comment: For taking notes `Knotes` is the preferred KDE tool. For your purpose, maybe an outliner like `KJots` is the right tool.

Comment: It's relevant but this question is about Kate, not software recommendations. `Knotes` is for sticky-notes not other notes-taking and `KJots` doesn't work in Debian11 ("The Akonadi personal information management service is not operational") but I will check if it features TOCs.

Comment: Create a bug report for Kjots [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=453631). And the issue about TOCs in Kate was a duplicate, progress can be tracked in the issue linked there. A good alternative that features TOCs (but currently only for markdown) is `QOwnNotes`.

Answer (score 0):

Look like Kate can't do this now ...

You can try Voom with vim ([Voom Screenshots](https://vim-voom.github.io/)), it can show TOC on split window, easy fold or move node (section).

Actually, I just want give a comment. (but I don't have enough reputation.)

If you meet *"The Akonadi personal information management service is not operational"* problem. You can change to sqlite backend.

1. `# apt install akonadi-backend-sqlite`  (in debian)
2. Follow guide in https://userbase.kde.org/Akonadi to

   1. Stop Akonadi, remove old Akonadi config and database.
   2. Create config for sqlite in `$HOME/.config/akonadi/akonadiserverrc`
   3. Start Akonadi
   4. (Optional) Use `akonadiselftest` command to test Akonadi server.

This tested in Debian 12.

---

But.... thanks `Igor Poboiko`'s very detail explication (in [bug page of Kjot](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=453631)).
I think I'll try another note application before Kjot. XD